# How to save and retrieve NSMutableDictionary in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary, nskeyedarchiver

Here is a code snippet that I attempted to use to store and retrieve a mutable dictionary in NSUserDefaults. As my values in the dictionary are custom objects, I am using the NSKeyedArchiver. When I attempt to archive or unarchive, a `NSInvalidArgumentException` is thrown.

```
// Save NSMutableDictionary to NSUserDefaults
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: dataDictionary];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: data forKey: key];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Retrieve dictionary from NSUserDefaults
NSData* data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: key];
NSMutableDictionary* dataDictionary = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data] mutableCopy];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this code is working fine. I just tried and it worked fine. Make sure that you allocate mutable dictionary again in a new dictionary obtained from `NSUserDefaults` is always immutable even if you write `mutableCopy` too

Comment: Show the whole error message. My guess is that objects inside `dataDictionary` are not `NSCoding` compliant. What kind of objects are inside `dataDictionary`?

Comment: The object inside dataDictionary are custom objects. Here is the full error message `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[customClass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: That's your issue. `customClass` has to be `NSCoding` compliant, and have `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: Okay, custom objects will throw the error. Implement `encode` and `decode` in your `CustomObject` implementation class

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, adding `- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` and `- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder` as well as implementing `NSCoder ` in the custom class did the trick. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder